# Using Regex to find multiple occurrences of a string, across a file - PHP

Tags: java, php, regex, string

I'm new to using Regex and was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

My problem is as follows:

I need to pattern match an entire file to determine if code meets a rule.
[Local Variable Could Be Final.](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.2.3/pmd-java/rules/java/optimizations.html#LocalVariableCouldBeFinal)
Essentially if the following code is within a file, I will need to check if the variable is assigned again. If not generate a warning to suggest an improvement.

```
public class Bar {
public void foo () {
    String txtA = "a"; // if txtA will not be assigned again it is better to do this:
    final String txtB = "b";
    }
}
```

I of course have to do this for many other examples but I've not been taught Regex and it's not part of my course, if you can suggest a pattern for this or provide a link to help me learn, I'd very much appreciate it.

Ideally I'd like to do this in one go, I could of course generate a set of variable occurrences and "scan" the file again to see if these appear < 2 times. But Regex is lightning fast, and I want to approach this in such a way that I can have one method and I'll simply pass in the pattern + string for matching.

I've had a go already and I can find multiple occurrences but if another variable is between two instances my Regex won't pick them up..

It's close, but I feel will not work in pretty much every scenario bar one.

Regex: `(\s*txtA\s*=\s*.*){2,}`

```
public class Bar {
public void foo () {
    String txtA = "a";       // matches
           txtA =  "ab";     // matches
    String txtB =  "xxx";    // breaks the match
           txtA =  "abc";    // doesn't match, but should.
}
```

}

If the above is the wrong way to approach this and you're aware of a more efficient way, perhaps some PHP Library, please do suggest.

Comment: PHP will perform the pattern match against a Java file.

Comment: `please do suggest.` - my suggestion: start by watching http://vimeo.com/groups/29150